# Why might \\* ("line break here, but no page break") not work, and how can one fix this?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, footnotes

One is often taught that "`\\` causes a line break which is not a paragraph break" and "the variant `\\*` additionally prevents a page break".

(I hereby acknowledge user `egreg`'s [admonition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151368/14996) that "`\\*` should not be used".)

But `\\*` often doesn't work! **When does `\\*` not work? How can one fix this?**

The following code produces a footnote example and then a body text example. Note that usage of `\\*` within body text is probably more common.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]\footnote{
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \\*
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \\*
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \\*
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \\*
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \\*
  % the pagebreak happens here
  last line}
\lipsum[5]


\lipsum[6-8]
\lipsum[2]

Line 1 \\*
  % the pagebreak happens here
Line 2 \\*
Line 3 \\*
Line 4 \\*
Line 5 \\
Line 6

\end{document}
```

Comment: Guide to the accepted answer: The answer to the **when** is intricate and has to do with penalties. (Above I've intentionally asked in a vague and open-ended way because a non-expert will know little about TeX's penalties, and maybe this is how it should be.) The/an answer to the **how to fix** is Heiko Oberdiek's excellent `\NLS` ("newline with star") macro, which simulates ``\\*`` (but has a potential side effect related to widows and orphans, explained in his answer).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Theory

`\\*` throws an error if used in vertical mode; in horizontal mode it does the following actions:

```
\unskip        % remove any preceding spaces
\vadjust{\penalty 10000}% \nobreak in vertical mode after this line
\penalty 10000 % \nobreak in horizontal mode
\hfil          % fill current line
\penalty-10000 % force line break
```

Thus it looks as if there was a `\nobreak` in vertical mode between the two lines that prevents a page break.

However, what happens if TeX puts the lines of a paragraph in the vertical list?

- It inserts interline glue between the boxes (depending on the values of `\baselineskip`, `\lineskiplimit`, and `\lineskip`). Glue after a non-discardable item would constitute a break point.
- Therefore TeX adds a penalty before the interline glue to control the page breaks. This penalty is `\interlinepenalty` plus some other penalties depending on the context (`\clubpenalty`, `\widowpenalty`, `\displaywidowpenalty`, `\brokenpenalty`). Then the break point is this penalty, not the interline glue.

The penalty added via `\vadjust` is put right after the current line before the interline penalty and interline glue. Thus we have:

```
\hbox                         % the line
\penalty10000                 % \nobreak via \vadjust
\penalty\interlinepenalty+... % interline penalty
\vskip                        % interline glue
\hbox                         % next line
```

Thus we have a break point if the interline penalty is smaller than 10000, despite using `\\*`. If the interline penalty is 10000 or greater, then we do not have a break point anyway with an additional `\nobreak` of `\\*` or without.

However, there is one case where `\\*` actually prevents a line break.
Namely "The TeXbook" is not always telling the truth: There is a situation, where TeX does *not* add a interline glue. It tries to be clever and rationalizes an interlinepenalty of value zero. It probably thinks: interline glue after `\hbox` – we have a break point; penalty of zero – neither good nor bad, since there is already a break point, we do not need it.
In appendix A in answer to exercise 14.26 can be found:

> (When the total penalty is zero, as between lines 3 and 4 in this case, no penalty is actually inserted.)

Then `\nobreak` of `\\*` kicks in:

```
\hbox          % line box
\penalty 10000 % of \\* via \vadjust
\vskip <interline glue>
\hbox          % next line
```

Voila, the page break is surprisingly prevented. Of course this over-optimization is not a "bug" (TeX is per definition bug-free, de facto),
let's call it a "design misfeature". ;-)

For illustration, an example for ini-TeX (or plain TeX) for experimenting/studying. Macro `\NPB` simulates `\\*`:

```
% iniTeX or plain TeX
\showboxbreadth=10000
\showboxdepth=10000
\tracingonline=1
\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2
\font\rm=cmr10
\rm
\baselineskip=12pt
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax
\hsize=2in
\vsize=4in

\interlinepenalty=1
\clubpenalty=-1
\widowpenalty=150

\def\NPB{% \\*
  \unskip
  \vadjust{\penalty10000}%
  \penalty10000\hfil\penalty-10000 %
}

\noindent
A\NPB B\NPB C

\scrollmode
\showlists
\end
```

Console output:

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\glue(\topskip) 0.0
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x144.54, glue set 137.03998fil
.\rm A
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\penalty -10000
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
\penalty 10000
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x144.54, glue set 137.45663fil
.\rm B
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\penalty -10000
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
\penalty 10000
\penalty 151
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x144.54, glue set 137.31776fil
.\rm C
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
total height 30.83331
 goal height 289.07999
prevdepth 0.0, prevgraf 3 lines

! OK.
l.28 \showlists
```

The stuff between the first lines/`\hbox`es:

```
\penalty 10000
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
```

The first penalty comes from `\vadjust{\penalty10000}`. The interline penalty sums up to zero: `\interlinepenalty` + `\clubpenalty` = 1 - 1 = 0

In the second case:

```
\penalty 10000
\penalty 151
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
```

the interline penalty is not suppressed: `\interlinepenalty` + `\widowpenalty` = 1 + 150 = 151. This penalty allows a page break at this place.

### Practice

The following part is inherited from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176494/16967) to the more specific [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172431/16967) variant.

The problem is the automatically inserted `\interlinepenalty`. It is usually smaller than 10000 and allows a page break even if it is preceded by a `\nobreak` (= `\penalty10000`).

The following uses a workaround. Instead of ending the line, the paragraph is ended. Then the effects of `\parskip` and `\parindent` need to be reversed and avoided:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\NLS}{%
  \par
  \nobreak
  \vspace{-\parskip}%
  \noindent
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]\footnote{
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \NLS
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \NLS
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \NLS
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \NLS
  no asterisk \\ asterisk \NLS
  last line}
\lipsum[5]  

\end{document}
```

> [image: page1] [image: page2]

However, this is still a workaround and does not provide a correct implementation for `\\*`. By splitting a paragraph in two paragraphs, up to two interline penalties for the line break before and after the inserted `\par` are increased by `\widowpenalty` or `\clubpenalty`. That is, additional page breaks can be forbidden as a side effect, if the addition by `\widowpenalty` or `\clubpenalty` now increases the  interline penalty to 10000.

The other case is less problematic: If the line break, where the `\par` gets inserted, would have get `\clubpenalty` or `\widowpenalty`, then this penalty is now lost. But since we forbid a page break already by `\nobreak`, a loss of an additional penalty does not matter.

Comment: I don't think that `\interlinepenalty` is the problem - if this were true `\\*` would never work - at least as long it has the value zero. If you add `\interlinepenalty=1` to the original example you can see the difference. In the text case the problem are club- and widowpenalty. In the footnote case perhaps also `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`. See also  http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/2411.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: TeX adds a inter line penalty that consists of `\interlinepenalty`. `\clubpenalty` and/or `\widowpenalty` is added, if the line break is after the first/before the last line. Only if this value is zero, then the `\nobreak` of `\\*` has an effect of preventing the page break at the interline glue. Otherwise there can be a page break, if the minimum of the inter line penalty or the `\nobreak` penalty is smaller than 10000.

Comment: If you try out some examples (normal text, not footnotes) you can see that the page breaks at `\\*` occur *only* after the first and before the last line of a paragraph. And if you set club and widow penalty to 10000 there will be no page breaks -- even if you have lots of `line\\*line\\*` in a row. As long as `\interlinepenalty` is zero it doesn't interfere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, if the interline penalties sum up to zero, then TeX suppresses the output of a `\penalty` and the `\nobreak` prevents the page break at the interline glue. This is a kind of "mis-feature". If someone increases `\interlinepenalty`, then a page break, that was formerly prevented, should not become possible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have added an iniTeX example; perhaps it makes the description clearer, if it can be studied with TeX's debugging facilities.

Comment: I think we are meaning the same but word it differently. I only wanted to make clearer that `\interlinepenalty` *alone* normally (with value 0) doesn't harm (and I don't think that this is "misfeature". How could you suppress a page break in a paragraph if it wouldn't work this way?). It's the combination/sum with the other penalties that let `\\*` break.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thus preventing a line break after the second line and before the second-last line of a paragraph with a special value zero for `\interlinepenalty` happens rather by accident than by design. You have cited a LaTeX bug report. There it was discussed to solve the issue in a cumbersome way by the output routine. Thus there is room for improvement at the engine level. In LuaTeX it could be solve by walking through the node lists to remove the interline penalties after the `\nobreak` penalty.