# Allow line breaks but not page breaks

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, page-breaking

How can I avoid that a `\parencite{key}` will get broken over 2 pages?

**Linebreaking is fine, but page breaking is not**. The reason I do not want this is that I have TIKZ customization for citations, which goes wrong with page breaking. Also linking goes (sometimes not always) wrong causing (`\pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink`)

I can solve this by `\mbox{\parencite{key}}` but then linebreaking is also not possible.

I can apply this `\mbox{\parencite{key}}` to only citations which breaks the compilation, however this can vary from time to time (depending on layout), so I am looking for a more generic solution which always work.

Thanks

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972, 
    Author = {William Labov}, 
    Year = {1972}} 
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,url=false,backref=true,bibencoding=ascii,firstinits=true,uniquename=init,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newbox\one
\newbox\two
\long\def\loremlines#1{%
    \setbox\one=\vbox { \lipsum }
   \setbox\two=\vsplit\one to #1\baselineskip
   \unvbox\two}
\begin{document}
\loremlines{46}
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books asdasdsad asdsad \parencite{Labov1972}.
\loremlines{1} 
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books asdasdsad asdsad \parencite{Labov1972}asdasdas asdasd asdsad
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Produces:**
 [image]

Comment: Can you provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we can play round with?

Comment: I have enhanced my post with MWE

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a penalty after the current line with `\vadjust` (the red example). But this is not fool proof (see the blue pages). E.g. in your example it wouldn't work as on the first and last line of a paragraph \clubpenalty and \windowpenalty can interfere (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179917/2388).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{26\baselineskip}

\lipsum*[1]
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books asdasdsad as \parencite{doody}.
\lipsum*[1]

\newpage\color{red}

\lipsum[1]
\vspace{26\baselineskip}

\lipsum*[1]
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books asdasdsad as \vadjust{\penalty10000}\parencite{doody}\vadjust{\penalty0}.
\lipsum*[1]


\newpage\color{blue}%\clubpenalty10000 %uncomment to see the difference

\lipsum[1]
\vspace{25\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1]
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books asdasdsad asblblblblb \vadjust{\penalty10000}\parencite{doody}\vadjust{\penalty0}.
\lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```